# How to open Siri with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, siri

I would like to open Siri with AppleScript, and I don't know how.

It has been very hard trying to find it in the official documentation.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to enable "Show Siri in menu bar" in System Preferences and run

```
tell application "System Events" to tell the front menu bar of process "SystemUIServer"
    tell (first menu bar item whose description is "Siri")
        perform action "AXPress"
    end tell
end tell
```

You have to enable the appropriate Accessibility sections in Security&Privacy